# How To validate a mobile number in java script?

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to validate a mobile number of 11 digit , where the 1st 3 digit will be `019 , 018 , 017 , 016` . How can I check this that the first 3 digit will be fall among the four criteria??

I can validate if the number is a character or is it less than 11 digit using the code bellow.Now the problem is I want to check If the 1st 3 digit fall into the four criteria( `019 , 018 , 017 , 016`)

```
var phoneno = /^\d{11}$/;  
  if(inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))  
  {  
      return true;  
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific case you could simply add a group `()` with the desired delimited `|` values:

```
/^(?=019|018|017|016)\d{11}$/
```

```
01711122233  // GOOD //  Has length 11 and starts with 017
017111222333 // BAD  //  Has length 12
11711122233  // BAD  //  Does not starts with either one from group
```

> ^ assert position at start of the string
>   (?=019|018|017|016) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex **below** can be matched
>   1st Alternative: 019
>   019 matches the characters 019 literally
>   2nd Alternative: 018
>   018 matches the characters 018 literally
>   3rd Alternative: 017
>   017 matches the characters 017 literally
>   4th Alternative: 016
>   016 matches the characters 016 literally
>   \d{11} match a digit [0-9]
>   Quantifier: {11} Exactly 11 times
>   $ assert position at end of the string

Answer (score 1):

```
var allowedFirstDigits = ["019", "018", "017", "016"];
var firstDigits = phoneNumber.substring(0, 3);
if (allowedFirstDigits.indexOf(firstDigits) < 0) {
    // Bad number
}
else {
    // First threee digits OK
}
```

Comment: should be String  `["019", "018",` not `[019, 018,`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regular expression: `/^01[6-9]\d{8}$`